# ScriptTagProxy in ExtJS doing an OPTIONS instead of GET?

Tags: extjs, cross-domain

That's about it. I'm trying to get some delicious cross-domain JSON and for some reason the method that's going through is OPTIONS, even though I've explicitly specified method:'GET' in the config for the ScriptTagProxy. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That seems impossible, since "ScriptTagProxy" is like adding a `<script src="url"></script>` in the html document.

So, the HTTP request should a GET, whatever the method you specify.

If you're sure that's "OPTIONS" which is called, maybe it's the browser you're using which makes an `OPTION` request before a `GET` ? (strange)

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge if you are making an OPTIONS hit, it means you are actually not using the scriptTagProxy but rather an HttpProxy, so maybe something is wrong in your config ? As timdev commented, code would help to identify the problem.